# Nominatim generic city geocode for all addresses

Tags: r, geocoding, nominatim

I wrote a script to geocode Austin (TX) addresses using Nominatim. All the addresses I wanted were geocoded to the same, generic center of the city address. When I use google maps, I get building level longitudes and latitudes.

Is there a way to get building level latitudes and longitudes using Nominatim? I was using a key from MapQuest for Nominatim geocoding. Code snippet for the actual call is below:

```
locations <- osm_geocode(head(clean_distinct_addresses$ADDRESS, 10), key = getOption("OSM_API_KEY","MY_API_KEY))
```

Comment: were you using the [nominatim](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim) package? You'll have to add some code to your question for others to be able to help.

Comment: Yes, I was using nominatim for R, installed from that GitHub repository with devtools.

Comment: can you also add the data for `head(clean_district_addresses)` ?